# When to use a database depending on need to filter/sort data?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm currently building a Flask web app, and I am trying to figure out if I need a database for the information that I'm displaying. I have looked at other posts, and found that depending on the size of data, it could better to just use objects instead. I started using objects, however I need to have the ability to filter/sort my data, and MySQL queries are faster then python sort. Also, my data gets updated daily, and contains about 400 data points. Is the trade off of adding a database worth the speed I'll gain from using a DB? Or should I look into other options like storing the data to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be worthwhile taking a look at the following.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190482/why-use-a-database-instead-of-just-saving-your-data-to-disk

Reiterating the excellent points Robert Harvey had made regarding why you should look at using a DB rather than storing to a file:

1.You can query data in a database (ask it questions).

2.You can look up data from a database relatively rapidly.

3.You can relate data from two different tables together using JOINs.

4.You can create meaningful reports from data in a database.

5.Your data has a built-in structure to it.

6.Information of a given type is always stored only once.

7.Databases are ACID.

8.Databases are fault-tolerant.

9.Databases can handle very large data sets.

10.Databases are concurrent; multiple users can use them at the same time without corrupting the data.

11.Databases scale well.